# List of Publishers

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, books-generally

I am looking for a list of publishers that are putting out seforim now a days. My reason is because I want to make a list of publishers in an effort to track down certain seforim. Many publishers (especially big ones) might own rights to seforim that they don't necessarily still publish for whatever reason. Or have them somewhere in their libraries, or know who owns the rights to them or actually copies. This comes from experience.

Specifically those that are publishing a large amount of seforim or have in their catalogs (or have the right to) many seforim. However really any publisher I am interested in knowing, even ones that publish a small amount of seforim (note that I said "specifically" the big ones, i.e. small also good.)

Two examples that I'll offer are Machon Yerushalayim and Mossad HaRav Kook.

Who else is there?

One may also include "projects" like the Frankel Rambam or Encyclopedia Talmudit where although they are putting out "one" type of seforim it's a set of seforim that is rather well-known and "big" in many regards.

My question boils down to mainly who are the big publishers today in seforim (comparable to the examples I give of Machon Yerushalayim and Mossad HaRav Kook. However even "less" than what they publish would also qualify (even significantly less) and certainly those that publish even more.

Comment: [tag:product-recommendation]? Are you looking for evaluations of the merits of the various publishers?

Comment: @DoubleAA ???? so take it off ....

Comment: Down to how small are you interested in?

Comment: @IsaacMoses anything really. Bigger ones more important. But anything is also good.

Comment: That's not what your second sentence or the first sentence in your last paragraph say.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier for answerers to intuit what should or should not be on the list if you include information about why you want this list.

Comment: @IsaacMoses better?

Comment: I think it's pretty much impossible that you'll get a comprehensive list of all contemporary publishers of seforim as an answer here. Maybe a link to something like such a list. I reiterate that adding more about your motivation would make this more answerable in a productive way.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Maybe it is, maybe it isn't...A link would also be good.

Comment: You lost me at "I'm looking for a comprehensive list..." -1

Comment: Macmillan, HarperCollins, Hachette, Warner,....

Comment: I've removed my downvote, but I still think this question is very vague and difficult to answer. When you try to clarify what you're looking for in an answer you have a tendency to expand the question. I think you should contract. Especially in this case. "I'm looking for a list of publishers of ___ Seforim."

Comment: @msh210 seforim, i.e. Jewish books

Comment: Artscroll, Feldheim, Targum, Israel Book Store... Names like that?

Comment: @HachamGabriel that and more

Comment: List questions don't work well for the Stack Exchange format.  If this question remains open, I recommend one community-wiki answer to compile the list.

Answer (score 4):

Yaakov Rosanes at Virtual Geula has a list of all active [Israeli publishers of seforim](http://www.virtualgeula.com/publisherslist/) as well as a lits of inactive publishers linked at the bottom of that page.  If you are searching for rare or hard to find books that is the place to go.

Comment: Awesome! I'm encouraging others to follow suit and help out with this. Publishers in America would also be good.

Comment: Please be aware that the author of this answer, "Michael Tzadok," has recently been [outed as a Christian missionary](https://www.northjersey.com/story/news/new-jersey/2021/05/03/orthodox-rabbi-nj-accused-double-life-missionary-israel/4868837001/). His real name is Michael Elk. Please also see [here](https://youtu.be/8N6sPqFBt3A) and [here](https://youtu.be/8g71VZrjCpg).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a community wiki for listing Jewish publishers.

- [Mossad haRav Kook](https://www.mosadharavkook.com)
- [Machon Yerushalayim](http://www.machonyerushalayim.com)
- [Koren](http://KorenPub.com) (inc. Maggid, et al.)
- [ArtScroll](http://ArtScroll.com) (inc. K'hal, et al.)
- [Feldheim](http://Feldheim.com)
- [Israel Book Shop Publications](https://www.israelbookshoppublications.com/store/pc/home.asp) (Also includes their Judaica store in Brookline, MA)
- [Hotzaat Moreshet](https://www.rinat-israel.co.il/en/89) (*Siddur Rinat Yisrael*)